# Count number of input fields with value with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this script that automatically generates a new text field when the previous one is being filled, then automatically advances the cursor to the next when the user types in an exclamation mark.  This works well.  Now, I'd like to add a line below the last text field that shows the number of these input boxes that have been created and have content.  Any help?

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <input type="text" name="qr[]" id="txt_1" class="qr" autofocus />
</div>
<script>
$('#myDiv').on('keyup', 'input', function(e) {
  if ($(this).val() == '') {
    $(this).next().remove();
    return;
  } else if ($(this).next().val() == '') {
    if (e.keyCode === 49 && e.shiftKey) {
      $(this).next().focus();
    }
    return;
  }

  addNewTxt($(this));
});

$('#myDiv').on('paste', 'input', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');

  if (!text) {
    return;
  }

  var textSections = text.split('!');

  $(this).val(textSections[0]);
  var lastEl;
  for (var i = 1; i < textSections.length; i++) {
    lastEl = addNewTxt($(this), textSections[i]);
  }

  lastEl.focus();
});

function addNewTxt(el, val) {
  var newTxt = el.clone();
  var id = newTxt.attr('id');
  newTxt.attr('id', 'txt_' + (parseInt(id.substring(id.indexOf('_') + 1))));
  newTxt.val(val || '');
  el.parent().append(newTxt);

  return newTxt;
}</script>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place to be asking for people to do your job for you. If you need to hire a programmer, try [careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do.

First add a div below the div containing your inputs:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <input type="text" name="qr[]" id="txt_1" class="qr" autofocus />
</div>
<div id="numInputs">
    Number of inputs: 1
</div>
```

Then in your javascript do a few things:

add a var to track the number of inputs - initialize it to 1

```
var numInputs = 1;
```

after you add an input increment the var

```
numInputs++;
```

after incrementing the var use jquery to change the html of the numInputs div to display the number to the user

```
$('#numInputs').html("Number of inputs: " + numInputs);
```